# Runtime error with ideone ,can anyone explan?

Tags: python, python-2.7

when i use https://ideone.com
it gave me Runtime error how can i solve this ?
code :

```
a = int(raw_input()) 
b = int(raw_input())
c = int(raw_input())
z = a + b + c
print z
```

Comment: What's the actual error? Use a real environment to get a real error. And what's the input you're using?

Comment: You need to give more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because on ideone for raw_input() you need to provide the inputs (click stdin or input to open the input entry box) BEFORE you actually run the program by pressing "Run" or "ideone it".

It is not an interactive shell like the python executable.

Sample:  https://ideone.com/MvI72f

The actual runtime error being throw is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: thanks , but when i solve my quiz at code forces it gaves me Runtime error aslo ,why that !

Comment: Probably for the same reason, or could be a bug in that code of yours.

Comment: i tested it in terminal it's run !